# Datatables fuga de memoria

Tags: jquery, datatables

Estoy teniendo problemas con una funcion que genera un Datatables.

La misma se ejecuta cada 30 segundos, en el ejemplo la pongo en 5, empieza a acumular memoria y no la libera. Revise por todos lados y no puedo encontrar la falla, la version que dejo para que me ayuden no contiene la llamada de ajax, que lo unico que hace es llamar un ASP que devuelve un XML, el mismo es parseado y agregado a una tabla que despues se convierte en datatable.

```js
var timerGrilla = setInterval(function(){

    var instGrilla = new getGrilla(); // genero grilla

    instGrilla = null; //vacio


}, 5000)

function getGrilla(){
// Variables
    var nsGrilla = { //namespace de la grilla
        sGrilla: "",
        xml: "",table: "",header: "",row: "",cellHeader: "",body: "",
        icoObjeto: "",ccheck: "",
        seleccionado: "",cell1: "",
        aVel: [],aTipo: [],aColor: [],aNombre: [],aGrupo: [],aRazonSocial: [],aFechaPosi: [],aUContacto: [],aHojaRuta: [],aUbicacion: [],aFechaTemp: [],aTemp1: [],aTemp2: [],aRumbo: [],aLat: [],aLon: [],aRadio: [],aGeoData: [],aIdRastreable: [],sHRNombre:"",
        gHRPadre:"",gHRDireccion:"",gHRLat:"",gHRLon:"",gHRId:"",aHRPadre: [],aHRDireccion: [],aHRLat: [],aHRLon: [],aHRId: [],
        gColor:"", gNombre:"", gGrupo:"", gRazonSocial:"", gUContacto:"", gFechaPosi:"", gVel:"", gHojaRuta:"", gUbicacion:"", gFechaTemp:"", gRumbo:"", gLat:"",
        gLon:"", gRadio:"", gGeoData:"", gIdRastreable:"", tipo:"",
    }

            // Construyo Grilla

        nsGrilla.sGrilla = document.createElement("table");
    
        nsGrilla.sGrilla.id="grilla";
        nsGrilla.sGrilla.width="100%";
        nsGrilla.sGrilla.height="500px";
        nsGrilla.sGrilla.border="0";
        nsGrilla.sGrilla.backgroundColor="black";
        nsGrilla.sGrilla.cellspacing = 0;
        nsGrilla.sGrilla.cellpadding = 0;
        
        nsGrilla.header = nsGrilla.sGrilla.createTHead();
        nsGrilla.row = nsGrilla.header.insertRow(0);
        nsGrilla.row.style = "font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;; font-size: 22px;";    

        nsGrilla.cellHeader = nsGrilla.row.insertCell(0); nsGrilla.cellHeader.style = "width:15px !important;"
        nsGrilla.cellHeader = nsGrilla.row.insertCell(1);
        nsGrilla.cellHeader = nsGrilla.row.insertCell(2); nsGrilla.cellHeader.id="header"; nsGrilla.cellHeader.innerHTML = "Nom / Dom";
        nsGrilla.cellHeader = nsGrilla.row.insertCell(3); nsGrilla.cellHeader.id="header"; nsGrilla.cellHeader.innerHTML = "Vel.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        nsGrilla.cellHeader = nsGrilla.row.insertCell(4); nsGrilla.cellHeader.id="header"; nsGrilla.cellHeader.innerHTML = "Ubicación";
        nsGrilla.cellHeader = nsGrilla.row.insertCell(5); nsGrilla.cellHeader.id="header"; nsGrilla.cellHeader.innerHTML = "Entidad";

        nsGrilla.body = nsGrilla.sGrilla.createTBody();
         
        for(i=0; i < 100; i++){    
            //correciones undefined
            var sRumbo = ""; var sVel = ""; var sFechaPosi = ""; var sTemperatura = "";
            var hasTemp = false;
            if(nsGrilla.aTemp1[i] >0){ hasTemp=true; }
            if(nsGrilla.aTemp1[i] === undefined){sTemperatura = "" }else{ sTemperatura = nsGrilla.aTemp1[i]}
            
            if(nsGrilla.aRumbo[i]===undefined){sRumbo=""}else{sRumbo=nsGrilla.aRumbo[i]}
            if(nsGrilla.aVel[i]===undefined){sVel=""}else{sVel=nsGrilla.aVel[i]}
            if(nsGrilla.aRazonSocial[i]===undefined){sRazonSocial = ""}else{sRazonSocial = nsGrilla.aRazonSocial[i]}
            if(nsGrilla.aFechaPosi[i]===undefined){sFechaPosi=""}else{sFechaPosi=nsGrilla.aFechaPosi[i]}
            if(nsGrilla.aUbicacion[i]===undefined){sUbicacion=""}else{sUbicacion=nsGrilla.aUbicacion[i]}

            //defino icono            
            if(nsGrilla.aTipo[i]=="Movil"){nsGrilla.icoObjeto = "img/ico-truck-blue.png";}
            if(nsGrilla.aTipo[i]=="Lugar"){nsGrilla.icoObjeto = "img/ico-flag-blue.png";}

         
            //agrego fila 
            nsGrilla.row = nsGrilla.body.insertRow(0);
            nsGrilla.row.style = "cursor:pointer;color:#f88a15";

            
            
            nsGrilla.cell1 = nsGrilla.row.insertCell(0); 
            //nsGrilla.cell1.innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox' id='"+ nsGrilla.aIdRastreable[i] + "'  " + nsGrilla.ccheck + " ><span style='display:none;'>" + nsGrilla.ccheck + "</span>"; // lo filtro por span
            nsGrilla.cell1.innerHTML = "PRUEBA"
            nsGrilla.cell1.style = "width:15px !important;"
            nsGrilla.cell1 = nsGrilla.row.insertCell(1); 
            //nsGrilla.cell1.innerHTML = "<div style='width:30px;background-color:#" + nsGrilla.aColor[i] + "'><img src=\'" + nsGrilla.icoObjeto + "'\" ></div><span style='display:none;'>" + nsGrilla.aTipo[i] + "</span>"; 
            nsGrilla.cell1.innerHTML = "PRUEBA"            
            nsGrilla.cell1.title = nsGrilla.aTipo[i]; nsGrilla.cell1.alt = nsGrilla.aTipo[i];

            nsGrilla.cell1 = nsGrilla.row.insertCell(2); 
            //nsGrilla.cell1.innerHTML = "<span>" + nsGrilla.aNombre[i] + "</span>";
            nsGrilla.cell1.innerHTML = "PRUEBA"
            nsGrilla.cell1.id = "tdNombre";
            nsGrilla.cell1 = nsGrilla.row.insertCell(3); 
            //nsGrilla.cell1.innerHTML = "<span>" + sVel + "</span>";
            nsGrilla.cell1.innerHTML = "PRUEBA"
            nsGrilla.cell1.id="tdVelocidad";
            nsGrilla.cell1 = nsGrilla.row.insertCell(4); 
            //nsGrilla.cell1.innerHTML = "<span>" + sUbicacion + "</span>";
            nsGrilla.cell1.innerHTML = "PRUEBA"
            nsGrilla.cell1.id="tdUbicacion";
            nsGrilla.cell1 = nsGrilla.row.insertCell(5); 
            //nsGrilla.cell1.innerHTML = "<span>" + sRazonSocial + "</span>";
            nsGrilla.cell1.innerHTML = "PRUEBA"
            nsGrilla.cell1.id="tdEntidad";
 
            }
            $("#grilla-datagrid").html("");
            $("#grilla-datagrid").html(nsGrilla.sGrilla);

            
            nsGrilla.table = $('#grilla').DataTable( {
                "paging":   false,
                "bInfo":    false,
                scrollY: "90vh",
                scrollX: true,
                scrollCollapse: true,
                deferRender:    true,
                order: [2, "asc"], 
                LengthChange: false,
                fixedHeaders:true,
                bPaginate: false,
                language: {
                    "decimal": "",
                    "emptyTable": "No hay información",
                    "info": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ Entradas",
                    "infoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 to 0 of 0 Entradas",
                    "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ total entradas)",
                    "infoPostFix": "",
                    "thousands": ",",
                    "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ Entradas",
                    "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                    "processing": "Procesando...",
                    "search": "Buscar:",
                    "zeroRecords": "Sin resultados encontrados",
                    "paginate": {
                        "first": "Primero",
                        "last": "Ultimo",
                        "next": "Siguiente",
                        "previous": "Anterior"
                    }
                    
                },
                
            } );


   
           
       
    }
```

```css
#grilla-datagrid {
    position: absolute;  z-index: 9999; left:0px; right: 0px; width: 70% !important; height: 100%; ;
    background-color: rgba(54, 64, 76, 0.514); 
    border: 1px #519eb0 solid;
    border-left:none;
    border-radius: 0px 16px 16px 0px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 6px;
    
}
th, td { white-space: nowrap;  }

div.dataTables_wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    left:0px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="grilla-datagrid"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Alguna idea de que puedo estar haciendo mal? Dejo el [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hug0gonzalez/4276z6fp/2/).

Comment: Hola! Bienvenido a Stack Overflow. 
Como no sabemos si jsfiddle cambie en el futuro o desaparezca, te recomiendo incluir el código relevante a tu pregunta *dentro* de la pregunta, como texto. Gracias!

Comment: Hola, gracias, pero es imposible meter ese codigo en un texto, mas alla de que necesito que lo ejecuten para que se den cuenta la falla. gracias!

Comment: Te ayudo a añadir el código porque no es imposible. Saludos! :)

Comment: Perdon, no entendia lo que me decias, ahora si, gracias. Tampoco sabia que jsfidle iba a desaparecer

Comment: No afirmo nada de jsfiddle. Simplemente stack overflow busca no depender de sitios externos.